# C# ASP.NET - Search AD for active and 'suspended' users

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I have a script which will execute when a user requests a new user.

This script will take the username provided by the user, and search AD to see if it exists. This works absolutely fine however our IT department have Expiry Dates on accounts. This results in the account being in some sort of 'suspended' state, not disabled, until it is moved to a separate OU for staff who have left.

The C# AD search is ignoring these suspended accounts.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Or does anyone have a clue as to how to accommodate for these users in the search?

```
public static string ADSearch(string ADPart, string Alias)
{
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry dirEntry = default(System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry);
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = default(System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher);
    try
    {
        dirEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://LDAP DETAILS HERE");

        dirSearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);
        dirSearcher.Filter = "(samaccountname=" + Alias + ")";

        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName");
        //Users first name
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
        //Users last name
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        //Users e-mail
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
        //Samaccount
        StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder(); //stuff them in | delimited


        SearchResult sr = dirSearcher.FindOne();
        //return false if user isn't found


        if (sr != null)
            if (ADPart == "GivenName")
                return sr.Properties["GivenName"][0].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            else if (ADPart == "sn")
                return sr.Properties["sn"][0].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            else if (ADPart == "mail")
                return sr.Properties["mail"][0].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            else if (ADPart == "alias")
                return sr.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            else
                return null;
        else
            return null;

        // return false if exception occurs
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Might be worth noting that I did not write this code and it was already in place.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that should work for you.

First, add "accountExpires" to `PropertiesToLoad`, then you can use this to see if the account is expired:

```
var isExpired = false;
if (sr.Properties.Contains("accountExpires")) {
    var expiry = (long)sr.Properties["accountExpires"][0];
    if (!expiry.Equals(9223372036854775807) && !expiry.Equals(0)) {
        isExpired = DateTime.FromFileTime(expiry) <= DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The magic numbers are because, as [the documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx), "A value of 0 or 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9223372036854775807) indicates that the account never expires."

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks so much for the details response. You certainly know what you're talking about. Unfortunately this does not suit my needs as the query is not seeing any expired accounts at all, so it can't count them. Thanks again!

Comment: This particular search is only searching for one account at a time, based on this: "(samaccountname=" + Alias + ")". So what is feeding the account names to this method?

Comment: There is a textbox where an admin can enter a username. Whatever they type is used in the search.

Comment: So are you saying that if they type in the username of an expired account, then it does not find anything?

Comment: Well, I've just been to talk to the Techs and it turns out that this whole issue was human error. The AD search actually works perfectly. Happy days. Thanks so much for your help Gabriel. I'll up vote your response as it certainly was educational.